# Design Layout differs from Runtime Layout

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a Project, where I am using prism for Navigation between usercontrols.
The App.xaml has some Definition for resources:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/GlobalResources.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

These are applied during design time and everything Looks the way it's supposed to. As I run the application the resources are not applied anymore. Resources referenced by key Work fine (e.g. BoolToVisConverter), but Resources applied to control types are ignored.

**Important**
The assumption made in the last sentence of the question is **wrong**.
Nothing is ignored during runtime - it's ignored during design time.

Comment: Can you post your usercontrol where the resources are not getting applied?

Comment: Can you share the project?

Comment: These resources are in a different assembly or the same one as the usercontrols ?

Comment: The usercontrols are in the same assembly as the resources are. As far I can see that, the problem applies to all resources, which are of the type `<style TargetType="SomeControlType" BasedOn="SomeControlType" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Investigation of the problem, it has nothing to do with the merged dictionaries, nor with resources not being applied during runtime.
The problem arises through a definition of a style for TextBlock:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2,3,2" />
</Style>
```

This style will be ignored during design time, but applied in runtime - thus leading to a different layout.

Adding explicit keys for resources or anything else are *not necessary*.

For testing purposes, if an design is applied or not just add some silly text-color or something like that - if I'd done that early, I would have found the problem in a jiffy.

Comment: Thing is, that my question is totally out of scope with the solution. The solution is "VS does not apply TextBlock style, but running app does", but the question is targeted on Prism, and _not loading_ (which in matter of fact does not occur). Additionally the merged resources are 100% disjunct.